# Doctrine redis caching: The option "query_cache" does not have a callable "setQueryCache"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have been following [this tutorial](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/docs/cache.md#example-with-redis) to set up doctrine (2.5) redis **second level** caching using the ZF2 DoctrineORMModule (version 1.0.0).

However, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\Stdlib\Exception\BadMethodCallException: 
The option "query_cache" does not have a callable 
"setQueryCache" ("setquerycache") setter method which must be defined in ...
```

I have created an [issue in the DoctrineORMModule repo](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/490), but I think I may have missed some necessary setup not mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: I noticed a bug in my configuration, I had placed my second level cache configuration under doctrine->driver->orm_default instead of doctrine->configuration->orm_default. This was the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall hitting the same brick wall trying to use the Doctrine Redis cache.  Instead I opted to use a Zend Cache adapter to get the Doctrine Cache working in the ZF2 module.

Here's how I did it.

First create a Zend Cache factory.  Below is one I wrote so my cache in now configurable instead of hard coded.  This has an added bonus that should you need to change cache servers or even cache engines, all you need to do is simply update the config.  This works great if you have multiple environments your working with (Development / Staging / Production).

modules/Application/Factory/CacheFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Factory;

use Zend\Cache\Storage\StorageInterface;
use Zend\Cache\StorageFactory;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class CacheFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    /**
     * Creates Service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator Zend Service Locator
     *
     * @return StorageInterface
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');

        return StorageFactory::factory(
            [
                'adapter' => [
                    'name' => $config['cache']['adapter'],
                    'options' => $config['cache']['options'],
                ],
                'plugins' => $config['cache']['plugins'],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Next create a Doctrine Cache Factory, this will place your configured Zend Cache service into a DoctrineModule\Cache\ZendStorageCache adaptor.

modules/Application/Factory/DoctrineCacheFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Factory;

use DoctrineModule\Cache\ZendStorageCache;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class DoctrineCacheFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    /**
     * Create Service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator Zend Service Manager
     *
     * @return ZendStorageCache
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        /** @var \Zend\Cache\Storage\StorageInterface $zendCache */
        $zendCache = $serviceLocator->get('Application\Service\Cache');

        return new ZendStorageCache($zendCache);
    }
}
```

Finally, wire everything up in the config.  Which config depends on your environment.  config/autoload/local.php might be a good starting place to add this.

```
<?php
return [
    'cache' => [
        'adapter' => 'Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Redis',
        'plugins' => ['Serializer'],
        'options' => [
            'server' => array(
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6379,
                'timeout' => 300,
            ),
            'namespace' => 'application_cache'
        ]
    ],

    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'Application\Service\Cache' => 'Application\Factory\CacheFactory',
            'doctrine.cache.doctrine_cache' => 'Application\Factory\DoctrineCacheFactory',
        ],
    ],

    'doctrine' => [
        'configuration' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'query_cache'       => 'doctrine_cache',
                'result_cache'      => 'doctrine_cache',
                'metadata_cache'    => 'doctrine_cache',
                'hydration_cache'   => 'doctrine_cache',
                'second_level_cache' => [
                    'enabled'               => true,
                    'default_lifetime'      => 200,
                    'default_lock_lifetime' => 500,
                    'file_lock_region_directory' => __DIR__ . '/../my_dir',
                    'regions' => [
                        'My\FirstRegion\Name' => [
                            'lifetime'      => 800,
                            'lock_lifetime' => 1000
                        ],
                        'My\SecondRegion\Name' => [
                            'lifetime'      => 10,
                            'lock_lifetime' => 20
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

All the available Zend Cache adapters and their settings can be found in the [Zend Framework Documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html)

I know this doesn't help you with the tutorial, but I hope this is of use to you anyway and gets you up and running.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Unfortunately, I still get the same error message using your method: The option "query_cache" does not have a callable "setQueryCache" ...

Comment: I tried this myself locally and it's working fine.  Do you know which version of the Service Manager + Doctrine Module you're running?

Comment: I'm using zend-servicemanger 2.7.6 and DoctrineORMModule 1.0.0

Comment: I've noticed a bug in my doctrine second level configuration, it works now. Thanks for your code sample anyway,your DoctrineCacheFactory example was very helpful for my implementation